# .onkeyup event listener for spacebar not working

Tags: javascript

```
console.log("Welcome - Press Space"); //prompting for space
document.onkeyup = function(event) //onkeyup listener
{
  if(event.keyCode == 32) //space
  {
    startGame(); //another function
  }
}
```

Trying to get feedback from the spacebar. I do not know how to proceed from this point.

Comment: seems to work for me https://codepen.io/TimCodes/pen/vJbBqB?editors=1011

Comment: what does your startGame function look like?

Comment: It is indeed working, might give more information regarding your problem

Comment: function startGame()
{
  bool = true;
}

Comment: bool is a boolean that triggers another function...

Comment: document.onkeyup = function(event)
{
  if(bool == true)
  {
    var key = event.key;
        for(var i = 0; i < cover.length; i++)
        {
            if(answer[i] === key)
            {
              cover[i] = key;
              if(!cover.includes("-"))
              {
                console.log("u won");
              }else{
                console.log(cover);
              }
            }

            document.getElementById('hidden-chars').innerText = cover.join('');
        }

  }
}

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. If you didn't talk about this please, could you give more information about your question.

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
 if(e.keyCode == 32 || e.which == 32) {
  console.log("...test")
 }
})
```